# Django: check for generic type in template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm using generic types in my `Profile` model:

```
user_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
details = generic.GenericForeignKey('user_type', 'object_id')
```

But now I want to check if a user is a certain type from within my template. I can get the user type with `{{ user.get_profile.user_type }}` but then what? Or how would I add a method to the model like `is_type_xxx` so that I could use it in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I don't fully understand the question, but it seems you can just define a function in your model that returns true if the type is what you need, then you can call that function from the template just as you would if you were accessing a variable.

In the model...

```
user_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
details = generic.GenericForeignKey('user_type', 'object_id')

def IsTypeX():
    return user_type == x
```

In the template...

```
{% if user.get_profile.IsTypeX %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: More precisely `return self.user_type == ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type)` but you're right.

Answer (score 1):

`user_type` is a `ForeignKey` to a [`ContentType` model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType), so treat it as you would any relation.

Answer (score 1):

Although Ignacio is basically correct, I find that there can be a really tendency to get a lot of unintended DB hits if you're not careful. Since the number of `ContentTypes` tends to be small and relatively unchanging, I cache a dict of name/id pairs to avoid it. You can use a signal to update your dict on the off chance a new ContentType is created.

You can then auto-create the necessary `is_type_xxx()` functions/methods as needed. It's a little klunky, but the code isn't very complicated.

Comment: Supposedly the framework already caches the content types to minimize db hits.

Comment: Yes, supposedly. Have you run the DB query stats and checked? And since you can't pass args in Django's template "language" you will still need to create (by hand or automatically) all of the necessary `is_type_xxx()` methods, something the ORM will *not* do for you. We have one app where there are over 150 ContentTypes (with more added on the fly), so it's a lot cheaper to do one fetch of the whole mess and build the dict and type-testing methods.